# Two modems two seperate lines to equal one speed

Tags: windows, networking, modem

I have two modems and two different phone/ internet lines coming into my home. Each line has 6mbps. Can I connect these two modems into one PC to combine the speed to 12 Mbps? Or is there a way to combine these two lines hardwired into one speed?

Comment: I need my hardwired speed to be increased into my PC so I was wanting to see if I could combine the two seperate harwired connections coming into my home

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 network cards for this to work. Both modems go into either network card, then from your network control center, you can create a bridged network that uses both connections and distribute the load across both.

Open Network and sharing center, at the left, go to Change adapter settings.

Rightclick the first network adapter, and choose Bridge connections, then select the second LAN to create the bridge. Note these LAN connections cannot be used for anything else. Only direct access to the internet.